# What is the difference between *(*uintptr) and **(**uintptr)

Tags: function, pointers, go

In Go's `runtime/proc.go`, there is a piece of code showed below:

> // funcPC returns the entry PC of the function f.
>   // It assumes that f is a func value. Otherwise the behavior is undefined.
>   // CAREFUL: In programs with plugins, funcPC can return different values
>   // for the same function (because there are actually multiple copies of
>   // the same function in the address space). To be safe, don't use the
>   // results of this function in any == expression. It is only safe to
>   // use the result as an address at which to start executing code.

```golang
//go:nosplit
func funcPC(f interface{}) uintptr {
    return **(**uintptr)(add(unsafe.Pointer(&f), sys.PtrSize))
}
```

What I don't understand is why not use *(*uintptr) instead of **(**uintptr)?

So I write a test program below to figure out.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)


func main(){
    fmt.Println()

    p := funcPC(test)

    fmt.Println(p)

    p1 := funcPC1(test)

    fmt.Println(p1)

    p2 := funcPC(test)

    fmt.Println(p2)
}

func test(){
    fmt.Println("hello")
}

func funcPC(f func()) uintptr {
    return **(**uintptr)(unsafe.Pointer(&f))
}

func funcPC1(f func()) uintptr {
    return *(*uintptr)(unsafe.Pointer(&f))
}
```

[image]

The result that p doesn't equal p1 makes me confused.
Why doesn't the value of p equal the value of p1 while their type is the same?

Comment: Because it's a pointer to a pointer?

Comment: Don't know Go, but I wonder what the value of `funcPC(p)` would be. What's the point of having a pointer to a pointer anyway.

Comment: @LukStorms: the, erm, point, of a pointer to a pointer, is to point to the pointer. If `pp` points to `p`, writing to `*pp` writes to `p` and reading from `*pp` reads from `p`. If `p` is in scope, that is of course a bit silly since you could just read from, or write to, `p` directly. But what if `p` is *not* in scope, or what if `pp` points to *either* `p` *or* `q` (depending on earlier logic), and you would like to use or update whichever pointer `pp` points to?

Comment: @torek Oh ok, so maybe not that pointless after all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Introduction

A function value in Go denotes the funtion's code. From far, it is a pointer to the function's code. It acts like a pointer.

From a closer look, it's a struct something like this (taken from `runtime/runtime2.go`):

```
type funcval struct {
    fn uintptr
    // variable-size, fn-specific data here
}
```

So a function value holds a pointer to the function's code as its first field which we can dereference to get to the function's code.

### Explaining your example

To get the address of a function('s code), you may use reflection:

```
fmt.Println("test() address:", reflect.ValueOf(test).Pointer())
```

To verify we get the right address, we may use [`runtime.FuncForPC()`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#FuncForPC).

This gives the same value as your `funcPC()` function. See this example:

```
fmt.Println("reflection test() address:", reflect.ValueOf(test).Pointer())
fmt.Println("funcPC(test):", funcPC(test))
fmt.Println("funcPC1(test):", funcPC1(test))

fmt.Println("func name for reflect ptr:",
    runtime.FuncForPC(reflect.ValueOf(test).Pointer()).Name())
```

It outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/03rj34aaD2m)):

```
reflection test() address: 919136
funcPC(test): 919136
funcPC1(test): 1357256
func name for reflect ptr: main.test
```

Why? **Because a function value itself is a pointer** (it just has a different type than a pointer, but the value it stores is a pointer) **that needs to be dereferenced to get the code address**.

So what you would need to get this to `uintptr` (code address) inside `funcPC()` would be simply:

```
func funcPC(f func()) uintptr {
    return *(*uintptr)(f) // Compiler error!
}
```

Of course it doesn't compile, [conversion rules](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) do not allow converting a function value to `*uintptr`.

Another attempt may be to convert it first to `unsafe.Pointer`, and then to `*uintptr`:

```
func funcPC(f func()) uintptr {
    return *(*uintptr)(unsafe.Pointer(f)) // Compiler error!
}
```

Again: conversion rules do not allow converting function values to `unsafe.Pointer`. Any pointer type and `uintptr` values may be converted to `unsafe.Pointer` and vice versa, but not function values.

That's why we have to have a pointer value to start with. And what pointer value could we have? Yes, the address of `f`: `&f`. But this will not be the function value, this is the address of the `f` parameter (local variable). So `&f` schematically is not (just) a pointer, it's a pointer to pointer (that both need to be dereferenced). We can still convert it to `unsafe.Pointer` (because any pointer value qualifies for that), but it's not the function value (as a pointer), but a pointer to it.

And we need the code address from the function value, so we have to use `**uintptr` to convert the `unsafe.Pointer` value, and we have to use 2 dereferences to get the address (and not just the pointer in `f`).

This is exactly why `funcPC1()` gives a different, unexpected, incorrect result:

```
func funcPC1(f func()) uintptr {
    return *(*uintptr)(unsafe.Pointer(&f))
}
```

It returns the pointer in `f`, not the actual code address.

Comment: I can't find any information in the  `conversion rules` about not allowing converting a `function value` to `uintptr`.

Comment: @polar9527 Exactly because there isn't. What is allowed is explicitly listed in the spec, and what is not there is not allowed. Look for the list starting with: _"A non-constant value `x` can be converted to type `T` in any of these cases..."_

Answer (score 0):

It returns a different value because **(**uintptr) is not the same as *(*uintptr). The former is a double indirection, the later a simple indirection.

In the former case, the value is a pointer to a pointer to a pointer to a uint.

Comment: Would you care to explain what the difference is between **(**uintptr) and just (uintptr)? Why is this **(**uintptr) syntax being used here?